# c++ qt libpoppler multithread issue

Tags: c++, qt, poppler

libpoppler-qt5.so is used. I use following code to extract text from PDF document:

```
QString pdf2txt(const char *buf, size_t len)
{

    Poppler::Document* document = Poppler::Document::loadFromData(QByteArray(buf, len));
    unique_ptr<Poppler::Document> doc_del(document);
    if (!document || document->isLocked()) throw runtime_error("pdf2txt document is locked or unavailable");

    const int pages = document->numPages();
    QString dst;
    for (int i = 0; i < pages; ++i)
    {
        Poppler::Page* page = document->page(i);
        if (!page) throw runtime_error("bad pdf document");
        unique_ptr<Poppler::Page> page_del(page);
        dst += page->text(QRect());
    }

    return dst;
}
```

But it segfaults when it`s used for several threads. For one thread it seems to be OK. Is this code thread safe? Are there any other thread-safe libs to extract text from PDF document? thank you

Comment: I`ve done with this library. It has segfaults and low quality text result. I created my own library to extract text https://github.com/uvoteam/pdf_extract

Answer (score 0):

According to [Bug 50992](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=50992) and the release notes, poppler is thread-safe by now.

However, I noticed the following line:

```
dst += page->text(QRect());
```

accesses the page pointer, although you created a unique_ptr page_del from this pointer before, which is not accessed. Could the unique_ptr be cleaned up before you access the pointer?